# Outlook addin- accounts loop

Tags: c#, outlook

I have the below code and currently my outlook profile has 2 accounts.
1. Mine(individual)
2. Company distribution list
And I have the below code

```
 Outlook.Accounts accounts = OutlookApp.Session.Accounts;
        foreach (var acc in accounts)
        {
            var myNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            var myAddressList = myNameSpace.GetGlobalAddressList();

            Debug.Write( myAddressList.AddressEntries.Count);
            foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry addressEntry in myAddressList.AddressEntries)
            {
               // Debug.Write(addressEntry.Name);
            }
```

I want to order list of accounts according to the individual address. how do we order  OutlookApp.Session.Accounts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LINQ OrderBy method:

```
Outlook.Accounts accounts = OutlookApp.Session.Accounts; 
foreach (var acc in accounts.OfType<Outlook.Account>().OrderBy(a => a.DisplayName)) 
{ 
    var myNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.Stores` collection  to access stores in your profile.